# In symfony, how to custom templates dynamically with js without ajax requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony

I'm working a lot on a symfony project but actually i didn't have any intuition on that problem. Someone can help me... Thank you !

Well, I'm creating an application with a map (leaflet). When a user clicks on a marker on a map, I want to display some information of this marker in a pop-up (like the image below, see *annex1*).
[annex1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W78z.jpg).
My problem is how to display it when the user click on the marker.

Well actually, when a user goes to the map page, all markers that are located around the user location are fetched from db to a variable in the template in a json format (see "annex2", bellow) to be able to retrieve it in js and add there to  map:

**annex2 :**

```
<script>
// To retrieve activities and display in the map.
var array_activities = {{ activities|json_encode()|raw() }};
</script>
```

Now is the part to display data when a user clicks on a marker. First solution was to create an Ajax request to the server then add it to the Twig pop-up template. But for my activity it's too many requests. That's why i prefer to fetch data in one time and then compute it in js.

**Here we are, in my main problem.** Actually i have to add all marker's information in the temmplate pop-up with js like this (*see annex3*).

*annex3:*

```
// get the popup block
let popup = document.getElementById("popupMap");

// retrieve containers to marker's information
let elements = popup.querySelectorAll("#data");

// then add data
elements[0].innerHTML = marker.name;
elements[1].innerHTML = marker.autor.username;
elements[2].innerHTML = marker.cate;
elements[3].innerHTML = marker.date;

// display popup block
popup.style.display = "block";
```

My question is do i have another way to do it in symfony with good performance? The cleaner way?
I thougth about websocket like socketIo. Is it a good solution to transfert data from js to my pop-up template?

Thank you for your answers. If you need more information tell me.

Comment: If all data is already written to the template, you don't need any AJAX. Also, if everything is already written to the template, this is no longer a Symfony problem

Comment: "*too many requests.*" - What do you mean with this? You only need one request to load all  activities/markers. Even if you load the marker's pop-up data if an user clicks on one, that's only one request per click. What makes you think an user would click all the markers (in unreasonable fast time)?

Comment: @NicoHaase Thank's to your answer. Yes all data are fetched when the user goes to the page and i know how to display it like the annex1. But i need also to make a dynamic redirection to the profil of the use that created the activity with twig syntax : " <a href="{{ path('mypath' }}"> </a>".

Comment: @DarkBee Thank's to your answer. I mean a Ajax request for each clicks on marker, to be able to using twig syntax and make it cleaner. Hmm i tought that even if a user make a request when he clicks on a marker, it will be to big if thousands users click in on one marker at the same time .... But i saw that in google map, each click on marker make a request, well maybe it's possible to do it...

Comment: If you're worried about that I'd suggest that you place all the "pop-ups" hidden inside the DOM and make them visible with javascript when a specific marker is clicked, .e.g `<div class="pop-up" data-marker-id="X">...</div>' and `<a href="#" data-toggle-marker="X">...</a>`

Comment: "I need also to make a dynamic redirection to the profil" - please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Why notadd the link to the invisible part as well?

Comment: Hmm... the redirection to the profile of the author is one of information that it fetch from db, that's why i didn't mention it.
But yes i understand your answers and I'm gonna fetch only the necessary data to display markers on the map like the GPS coordinates and if a user clicks on a marker, make an Ajax request, thank you!